# Regular expression containing anchor ( $ ) when matched with an input shows unexpected result in the following program, Why?

Tags: java, regex

```
/*
    patString: it$
    input: this is it
    the output at 2 to the match operation at 1 is false, why?
*/

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.Console;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        Console con = System.console();
        String patString, input;
        patternString  = con.readLine("Enter pattern: "); //pattern 
        input =  con.readLine("input: "); // input string to match against pattern
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        boolean testMatch = matcher.matches(); //1
        System.out.println("match found: " + testMatch); //2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `Matcher.matches()` method tries to match the whole string against the given pattern, or in other words, it has an implicit `^...$` surrounding the pattern.

You want the `find()` method

From the javadoc for [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

- [matcher()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29): Attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern
- [find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29): Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Comment: A better explanation would be: `Matcher.matches()` tries to match the whole string against the given pattern.

Comment: @khachik: You're right, I've changed it.  Just that the more "user-friendly" description doesn't work for me: I find it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Matcher.matches()` tries to match the whole string against the pattern

> `public boolean matches()`
>
> > Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
> >     If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.
> >
> > Returns:
> >     true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

See [Matcher.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)